# Monit losing bash variable?

Tags: bash, monit

Trying to get monit to monitor a custom daemon we wrote, and it's just not working with the bash stop/start script. If I run the stop/start script by hand from the command line it's working 100% perfectly, every single time. If it get's executed through monit, the variables is empty. Extract from the script where I am having problems:

```
GETPID=$(ps aux | grep unicorn | grep master | cut -d" " -f7)
echo "getPID : $GETPID"                                             
echo $GETPID > $PIDFILE
```

The `$GETPID` variable is blank when this gets executed with monit. By hand it works perfectly.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does it help if you add a shebang line `#!/bin/sh` as the first line of the file?

Comment: got a #!/bin/bash as the first line, the above code is really just a extract from the script.

Comment: Does it help if you use `awk '{print $2}'` instead of `cut` since `cut` is fragile to changes in whitespace?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why not use `pgrep` or `pidof` to get your PIDs?

Comment: don't have pgrep or pidof installed, it's a custom, extremely barebones linux install on a "appliance". awk gives same result, works from cmd line but not monit.

Comment: It's possible that `monit` launches the script in such a way that the she-bang is ignored, but I don't see anything that would cause `sh` to make `GETPID` empty.

Comment: Try echoing `$PATH` to a file from within your script. Run it by hand, then within monit. If `$PATH` is empty when run within monit, you will have to supply the full path to `ps`within your script. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819944/proper-way-to-run-a-script-using-cron for more information on launching non-interactive scripts.

Comment: At the top of the script, redirect stderr to a file (`exec 2>/tmp/log`), and invoke `set -x`; then examine the log file after your script has been run. Edit anything particularly interesting into the question -- this will show things like the empty-PATH case the proposed question is asking about (by having commands like ps emit not-found errors to stderr).

Comment: Better advice would be to set the PATH at the top of the script, or source any OS-provided scripts for setting up the default environment (`/etc/profile`?), rather than using full paths.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not a very good idea to parse the output of `ps` or `ls`.

You can write a simple `pgrep` using `find` on the `proc` filesystem:

```
# find /proc/ -maxdepth 2 -type l -name exe -lname '/bin/bash' -printf '%h\n' 2>/dev/null | sed 's/.*\///'
3580
3595
9504
9869
10054
10156
10193
# pgrep bash
3580
3595
9504
9869
10054
10156
10193
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Problem was path to unicorn in rvm install.